# После перезагрузки базы данных соединение не пересоздается mybatis spring boot

Tags: spring, mybatis

После перезагрузки базы данных (так же при сбросе соединений в ней) - запросы перестают исполняться, при этом новое соединение не создаётся.
Программа использует SingleConnectionDataSource, так как есть строгая необходимость использования максимум 1 соединения к базе данных.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>work</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcc</artifactId>
            <version>11.5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-b32</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

```
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate;
import org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@MapperScan(basePackages = {"example.work.mapper"},sqlSessionTemplateRef = "sampleSqlSessionTemplate")
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @Bean("oneDataSourceProps")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.pkks")
    public DataSourceProperties appDatabaseProperty() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }
    @Bean(name = "sampleDataSource")
    public SingleConnectionDataSource sampleDataSource(@Qualifier("oneDataSourceProps") DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
        SingleConnectionDataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .username(dataSourceProperties.getUsername())
                .password(dataSourceProperties.getPassword())
                .url(dataSourceProperties.getUrl())
                .driverClassName(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName())
                .type(SingleConnectionDataSource.class)
                .build();
        dataSource.setSuppressClose(true);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "sampleSqlSessionFactory")
    @Primary
    public SqlSessionFactory sampleSqlSessionFactory(@Qualifier("sampleDataSource") DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean bean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        /* При настройке нескольких источников данных здесь необходимо настроить конфигурацию mybatis */
       // bean.setMapperLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath*:mapper/**/*.xml"));
        bean.setTypeAliasesPackage("com.beans");
       // bean.setConfigLocation(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResource("mapperconfig/mybatis-config.xml"));
        return bean.getObject();
    }
//
//    @Bean(name = "sampleTransactionManager")
//    @Primary
//    public DataSourceTransactionManager sampleTransactionManager(@Qualifier("sampleDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
//        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
//    }
//
    @Bean(name = "sampleSqlSessionTemplate")
    @Primary
    public SqlSessionTemplate sampleSqlSessionTemplate(@Qualifier("sampleSqlSessionFactory") SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory) throws Exception {
        return new SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactory);
    }
//
//    @Bean(name = "sampleJdbcTemplate")
//    public JdbcTemplate sampleJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("sampleDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
//        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
//    }
}
```

```
import example.work.MainApplication;
import example.work.services.PlanService;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class ApiController {

    private final PlanService planService;

    public ApiController(PlanService planService) {
        this.planService = planService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/adminClearStart")
    public boolean clearStart()
    {
        System.out.println("перезагрузка " + (new Date()));
        MainApplication.restart();
        return true;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/getData")
    public List<Integer> getPlan() throws InterruptedException {
        return planService.planOfCache();
    }

}
```

```
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Select;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Mapper
@Repository
public interface WfMapper {

    @Select("SELECT groupid FROM public.groups")
    List<Integer> getAllRetiree();

}
```

```
import org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;


@SpringBootApplication (exclude = {
        MybatisAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class
})
public class MainApplication {

    private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        context = SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }

    public static void restart(){
        ApplicationArguments args = context.getBean(ApplicationArguments.class);

        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            context.close();
            context = SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args.getSourceArgs());
        });

        thread.setDaemon(false);
        thread.start();
    }

}
```

```
server.port=81
spring.datasource.pkks.username=postgres
spring.datasource.pkks.password=7895123
spring.datasource.pkks.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
mybatis.configuration.map-underscore-to-camel-case=true
```

Код ошибки

```
2023-01-05 16:02:24.534  WARN 25352 --- [p-nio-81-exec-5] o.s.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory    : Error while extracting database name

org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection was closed in SingleConnectionDataSource. Check that user code checks shouldClose() before closing Connections, or set 'suppressClose' to 'true'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:363) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory.resolveErrorCodes(SQLErrorCodesFactory.java:235) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.lambda$setDataSource$0(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:140) [spring-jdbc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.util.function.SingletonSupplier.get(SingletonSupplier.java:97) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.setDataSource(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:141) [spring-jdbc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.<init>(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:102) [spring-jdbc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.lambda$new$0(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:55) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.initExceptionTranslator(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:106) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:88) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:441) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.selectList(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:224) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:147) ~[mybatis-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:80) ~[mybatis-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy$PlainMethodInvoker.invoke(MapperProxy.java:145) ~[mybatis-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:86) ~[mybatis-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.getAllRetiree(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.getAllRetiree(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at example.work.services.PlanService.planOfCache(PlanService.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at example.work.controller.ApiController.getPlan(ApiController.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection was closed in SingleConnectionDataSource. Check that user code checks shouldClose() before closing Connections, or set 'suppressClose' to 'true'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:82) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:337) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 79 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection was closed in SingleConnectionDataSource. Check that user code checks shouldClose() before closing Connections, or set 'suppressClose' to 'true'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource.getConnection(SingleConnectionDataSource.java:167) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 80 common frames omitted

2023-01-05 16:02:24.535  WARN 25352 --- [p-nio-81-exec-5] o.s.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory    : Error while extracting database name

org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection was closed in SingleConnectionDataSource. Check that user code checks shouldClose() before closing Connections, or set 'suppressClose' to 'true'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:363) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory.resolveErrorCodes(SQLErrorCodesFactory.java:235) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.lambda$setDataSource$0(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:140) [spring-jdbc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.util.function.SingletonSupplier.get(SingletonSupplier.java:97) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.util.function.SupplierUtils.resolve(SupplierUtils.java:40) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.getSqlErrorCodes(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:171) [spring-jdbc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:193) [spring-jdbc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:91) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:441) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.selectList(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:224) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:147) ~[mybatis-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:80) ~[mybatis-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy$PlainMethodInvoker.invoke(MapperProxy.java:145) ~[mybatis-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:86) ~[mybatis-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.getAllRetiree(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.getAllRetiree(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at example.work.services.PlanService.planOfCache(PlanService.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at example.work.controller.ApiController.getPlan(ApiController.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection was closed in SingleConnectionDataSource. Check that user code checks shouldClose() before closing Connections, or set 'suppressClose' to 'true'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:82) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:337) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 79 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection was closed in SingleConnectionDataSource. Check that user code checks shouldClose() before closing Connections, or set 'suppressClose' to 'true'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource.getConnection(SingleConnectionDataSource.java:167) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 80 common frames omitted

2023-01-05 16:02:24.542 ERROR 25352 --- [p-nio-81-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Ошибка ввода/вывода при отправке бэкенду
### The error may exist in example/work/mapper/WfMapper.java (best guess)
### The error may involve defaultParameterMap
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: SELECT groupid FROM public.groups
### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Ошибка ввода/вывода при отправке бэкенду
; Ошибка ввода/вывода при отправке бэкенду; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Ошибка ввода/вывода при отправке бэкенду] with root cause

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему сам.
Отказался от своего конфигуратора (удалил его полностью)

добавил в application.properties
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=1

Главная задача была использовать максимум 1 соединение и данное решение оказалось оптимальным